# Получить System.Drawing.Font из System.Windows.Media.FontFamily

Tags: c#, wpf, шрифты

Есть приложение на WPF, которое отображает график в реальном времени. В целях производительности отрисовка сделана с помощью System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap и System.Drawing.Graphics. Также нужно отрисовывать текст, используя сторонний шрифт. В WPF для работы с шрифтами используется System.Windows.Media.FontFamily. FontFamily задается в отдельной сборке темы, там же хранятся и сами шрифты. Для отрисовки текста мне нужен объект System.Drawing.Font. Есть способ как получить Font из FontFamily?

System.Drawing.Font можно получить из  System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection, но для этого нужно передать в нее путь к файлу шрифта. Файлы шрифта пакуются в отдельную сборку с темой, можно их оттуда достать и передать в PrivateFontCollection или нужно их добавлять как отдельные файлы?

Comment: А почему вы в WPF рисуете не в XAML?

Comment: XAML не подходит из-за производительности. Или Вы имели ввиду использовать метод protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc) {}  для отрисовки?

Comment: Вот как раз наоборот, если вы будете применять его так, как надо, то производительность будет у вас на уровне. А надо - использовать привязки и MVVM подход, где XAML (UI), отделен будет от основного кода, то есть у вас в классах (VM/M) происходит вся логика. а XAML лишь ее сам, когда ему надо, отображает то, что надо.

Comment: В проекте так и сделано. Данные приходят несколько раз в секунду и отрисовывая их, используя объекты XAML имеем большое падение производительности. Поэтому отрисовка идет на низком уровне, а потом это отображется в родительском XAML объекте. Вопрос то в другом, как прокинуть на этот низкий уровень сторонний шрифт. При этом по возможности, используя FontFamily  родительского объекта.

Comment: Как вы делаете отрисовку через XAML? `myGrid.Children.Add(...);`?

Comment: Я не делаю отрисовку через XAML. В XAML есть Image, в Source которого установлен WritableBitmap. Вся отрисовка идет через WritableBitmap.

Comment: Ну вопрос у меня тот же, вы говорите, что страдает производительность, если использовать XAML, но как вы его используете мне не ясно. Вот если вы делаете "не производительный" вариант, используете по стандарту XAML, вы используете там привязки? Вы можете удалить все в XAML (кроме окна) и запустить проект? Запуститься ли он? Предположу, что нет и привязок как таковых у вас нет, от сюда и ваши проблемы с производительностью.

Comment: Я Вам за одно, Вы мне о другом =). Есть у меня привязки, через них данные в контрол передаются. А контрол уже обрабатывает эти данные и делает отрисовку.

Comment: Давайте поясню к чему я это: Я считаю, вы делаете сейчас костыль, почему? Потому что на такой низкий уровень очень редко когда надо спускаться. В WPF есть много механизмов, которые позволяют добиться хорошей производительности и если делать проект по правилам, использовать MVVM, использовать виртуализацию, асинхронность, то вы вообще не заметите каких либо проблем с производительностью. И тут я уверен, что ваш проект не входит в число тех единиц, которым надо опускаться на уровень ниже. Но увы, это лишь догадки, ибо вы не показываете как и что делаете. Так что желаю удачи в решение проблемы.

Comment: Как получить Font из FontFamily: просто используйте [конструктор](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), который принимает FontFamily одним из параметров.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15949087/5045688 - добавить шрифт из ресурсов

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я [рисовал график](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536945/12888024) полигоном, более 200 точек сильно тормозит, при чем производительность больше зависит от площади полигона, а не от количества точек. Думаю, `WritableBitmap` - вполне вменяемое решение. А автору рекомендую эту ссылку посмотреть, там как раз MVVM.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, c конструктором Font, есть небольшая загвоздка, он принимает  System.Drawing.FontFamily, а WPF использует System.Windows.Media.FontFamily. Нужно придумать как одно превратить в другое, если это возможно. Ну или использовать файл шрифта, как указано в ссылке в Вашем втором коментарии.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, то что можно было обрабатывать в ViewModel, там и обрабатывается. Расчеты же для отрисовки и сама отрисовка обрабатывается в контроле графика. Кроме отрисовки также есть и взаимодействие пользователя с графиком и переносить это в VM не самое лучшее решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напрямую получить System.Drawing.FontFamily, из System.Windows.Media.FontFamily не получилось. Но получилось извлечь файл шрифта из сборки с темой, и используя его, создать System.Drawing.Font. Правда получение потока с файлом шрифта немного сложнее, чем казалось изначально. Указатель на поток шрифта можно получить как через Marshal, так и через unsafe код. **Важно! Нужно хранить ссылку на PrivateFontCollection, пока в приложении используется шрифт, иначе получим исключение при попытке доступа к шрифту.**

```
private static PrivateFontCollection pfc;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var assemblyName = (string)Application.Current.FindResource("assemblyName_Key");
        var fontName = (string)Application.Current.FindResource("fontName_Key");
        var fontSize = (float)Application.Current.FindResource("fontSize_Key");

        var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().First(x => x.GetName().Name == assemblyName);
        var strResources = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources";
        var rStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(strResources);
        var resourceReader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(rStream);
        
        var fontStream = (Stream)resourceReader.OfType<System.Collections.DictionaryEntry>()
            .First(x => x.Key.ToString().IsOrdinalEqualsIgnoreCase(fontName)).Value;
        byte[] fontBytes = new byte[fontStream.Length];
        fontStream.Read(fontBytes, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);
        fontStream.Close();

        pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

        var fontData = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontBytes.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(fontBytes, 0, fontData, fontBytes.Length);
        
        pfc.AddMemoryFont(fontData, fontBytes.Length);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontData);

        //unsafe
        //{
        //    fixed (byte* pFontData = fontBytes)
        //    {
        //        pfc.AddMemoryFont((IntPtr)pFontData, fontBytes.Length);
        //    }
        //}

        Context.TextFont = new System.Drawing.Font(pfc.Families[0], fontSize);
    }
```